# Make the Tor interface an httpproxy

Tags: torsocks

Tor uses a SOCKS5 interface to communicate with applications.  I am making an application with winHttp that needs to use Tor, but winHttp only can use HTTP proxies.  Is there any way to change Tor's 'interface' proxy to an HTTP one instead of a SOCKS5 proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. Because Tor is made in that way, you should modify Tor's source code and so on. But, there is a "solution". You can use [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/), [ProxyChains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/%20ProxyChains) or other tools.

Comment: I will probably end up hacking in a http proxy that forwards stuff to Tor's socks5.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: Try out Polipo, is a http proxy that can communicate with socks proxy.